# Logistic regression from scratch: error keeps increasing

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, logistic-regression, gradient-descent

I have implemented logistic regression from scratch, however when I run the script the algorithm always predict the wrong label.
I've tried changing the training output and test_output by switching all 1 to 0 and vice versa but it always predict the wrong label.
I also noticed that changing the "-" sign to "+", when updating the weigths and the bias, the script correctly predicts the label.
What am I doing wrong?
This is the code I've written:

```
# IMPORTS
import numpy as np

# HYPERPARAMETERS
EPOCHS = 1000
LEARNING_RATE = 0.1

# FUNCTIONS
def sigmoid(z):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))


def cost(y_pred, training_outputs, m):
    j = - np.sum(training_outputs * np.log(y_pred) + (1 - training_outputs) * np.log(1 - y_pred)) / m
    return j


# ENTRY
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    # Training input and output
    x = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1]])
    training_outputs = np.array([1, 0, 1])

    # Test input and output
    test_input = np.array([[0, 1, 1]])
    test_output = np.array([0])

    # Weigths
    w = np.array([0.3, 0.3, 0.3])

    # Biases
    b = 0

    m = 3

    # Training
    for iteration in range(EPOCHS):
        print("Iteration n.", iteration, end= "\r")
        
        # Compute log odds
        z = np.dot(x, w) + b

        # Compute predicted probability
        y_pred = sigmoid(z)

        # Back propagation
        dz = y_pred - training_outputs
        dw = np.dot(x, dz) / m
        db = np.sum(dz) / m

        # Update weights and bias according to the gradient descent algorithm
        w = w - LEARNING_RATE * dw
        b = b - LEARNING_RATE * db

    print("Model trained. Proceeding with model evaluation...")

    # Test
    # Compute log odds
    z = np.dot(test_input, w) + b

    # Compute predicted probability
    y_pred = sigmoid(z)
    print(y_pred)
    
    # Compute cost
    cost = cost(y_pred, test_output, m)

    print(cost)
```

Comment: Could you expand from three to IDK maybe a dozen training examples? Which show more of a distribution than just 0 / 1 ? Here is my difficulty. There must be some ground truth generating function ( + error ) behind those examples, right? As a human, when I stare at them, it appears to me that the middle value is an ignored distractor variable, and the response is perhaps the mean of first and last input values. But focusing on first and last, you only offered (0, 0) and (1, 1) examples. Yet the test case is (0, 1) and you're hoping for response of 0. I can't imagine how one might learn that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an incorrect assumption pointed out by @J_H:

```py
>>> from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1]])
>>> y = np.array([1, 0, 1])
>>> clf = LogisticRegression().fit(x, y)
>>> clf.predict([[0, 1, 1]])
array([1])
```

`scikit-learn` at appears to believe that `test_output` should be a `1` rather than a `0`.

A few more recommendations:

- `m` should be fine to remove (it's a constant, so it could be included in the `LEARNING_RATE`)
- `w` should be initialized proportional to the number of columns in `x` (i.e., `x.shape[1]`)
- `dw = np.dot(x, dz)` should be `np.dot(dz, x)`
- Prediction in logistic regression depends on a threshold, usually `0.5`

Taking this into account would look something like the following.

```py
# Initialize weights and bias
w, b = np.zeros(X.shape[1]), 0

for _ in range(EPOCHS):
    # Compute log odds
    z = np.dot(x, w) + b

    # Compute predicted probability
    y_pred = sigmoid(z)

    # Back propagation
    dz = y_pred - training_outputs
    dw = np.dot(dz, x)
    db = np.sum(dz)

    # Update
    w = w - LEARNING_RATE * dw
    b = b - LEARNING_RATE * db

# Test
z = np.dot(test_input, w) + b
test_pred = sigmoid(z) >= 0.5
print(test_pred)
```

And a complete example on random train/test sets created with `sklearn.datasets.make_classification` could look like this—which usually gets within a few decimals of the `scikit-learn` implementation as well:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import numpy as np

EPOCHS = 100
LEARNING_RATE = 0.01

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=5)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

    # Initialize `w` and `b`
    w, b = np.zeros(X.shape[1]), 0

    for _ in range(EPOCHS):
        z = np.dot(X_train, w) + b
        y_pred = sigmoid(z)
        dz = y_pred - y_train
        dw = np.dot(dz, X_train)
        db = np.sum(dz)
        w = w - LEARNING_RATE * dw
        b = b - LEARNING_RATE * db

    # Test
    z = np.dot(X_test, w) + b
    test_pred = sigmoid(z) >= 0.5
    print(accuracy_score(y_test, test_pred))
```